# How do I make Dagger 1 and Dagger 2 coexist together in one Android project?

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2, dagger, shadowjar

We have a huge codebase to migrate from dagger 1 to dagger 2 but we would like to do it step by step. For that we were thinking to have both versions as our project dependency and do the migration module by module. But we were unable to make it work. This is the article we referred https://fernandocejas.com/2016/08/03/android-dagger-1-and-2-living-together/ but without any luck or is there any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no other way.

**When trying to use both Dagger versions together, you might run into different situations like classpath clashes and conflicts or transitive dependencies issues. So, in order to avoid them, we have to somehow relocate Dagger 2 packages.**

As the text said.

Comment: But I am not able to relocate Dagger 2 package with the latest android build tool and gradle version by following the steps in the article. Can you help?